# Why is my binary search tree overloaded move assignment operator not deleting correctly based on my code?

Tags: c++, tree, binary, variable-assignment, move

**BST.cpp's overloaded move assignment operator:**

```
BST& BST::operator=(BST&& otherBST) {
    if (this != &otherBST) {
        if (root) {
            stack <Node*> nodeStack;
            nodeStack.push(root);

            Node *currentNode = nullptr;
            while (!nodeStack.empty()) {
                currentNode = nodeStack.top();
                nodeStack.pop();

                if (currentNode->rlink) {
                    nodeStack.push(currentNode->rlink);
                }
                if (currentNode->llink) {
                    nodeStack.push(currentNode->llink);
                }

                delete currentNode;
                currentNode = nullptr;
            }
            cout << root << endl; // This is where it seems like root is not being deleted correctly/nullptr'd.
        }

        root = move(otherBST.root);
        otherBST.root = nullptr;
    }
    else {
        cerr << "ERROR: Cannot assign to self." << endl;
    }

    return *this;
}
```

Look at the cout << root << endl part that I commented on. When that piece of code is ran it prints out an address other than 00000000. It doesn't seem like they're being deleted correctly.

This is a code where the calling object's BST is deleted (all branches) and then it steals otherBST's tree. Move assignment operator. **But why is it not printing a nullptr and instead printing another address? It doesn't seem like it's being deleted correctly.**

Here's for reference:

This is the screenshot of test driver being ran: [click here to see.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBCSn.png)

**Main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Test.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    runTest();

    cout << endl << endl;
    system("Pause");
    return 0;
}
```

**Test.h**

```
#include "BST.h"

void runTest() {
    cout << "--------------------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "Binary Search Tree Test Driver" << endl;
    cout << "--------------------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
    // Initialization:
    BST bst1;
    // Traversal when there are no elements in the tree:
    cout << "BST traversal when there are no elements within the tree (bst1): " << endl;
    bst1.preorderTraversal();
    cout << endl;
    cout << "BST, inserting one element into the tree recursively and non-recursively (bst1): " << endl;
    bst1.insert(21);
    bst1.preorderTraversal();
    cout << endl;
    bst1.insert(69);
    bst1.preorderTraversal();
    cout << endl;
    cout << "BST, inserting duplicate elements into the tree recursively (bst1): " << endl;
    bst1.insert(32);
    bst1.insert(32);
    bst1.preorderTraversal();
    cout << endl;
    cout << "BST using the function destroyTree (bst1): " << endl;
    bst1.destroyTree();
    bst1.preorderTraversal();
    cout << endl;
    cout << "BST copy constructor by copy constructing bst1 (bst2): " << endl;
    bst1.insert(21);
    bst1.insert(69);
    BST bst2(bst1);
    bst2.preorderTraversal();
    cout << endl;
    cout << "BST move constructor by move constructing bst1 (bst3): " << endl;
    BST bst3 = move(bst1);
    bst3.preorderTraversal();
    cout << endl;
    cout << "BST move assignment operator by move assigning bst2 (bst1) when bst1 has no elements in its tree: " << endl;
    bst1.destroyTree();
    bst1 = move(bst2);
    bst1.preorderTraversal();
    cout << endl;
    bst1.destroyTree();
    bst2.destroyTree();
    cout << "BST move assignment operator by move assigning bst2 (bst1) when bst1 already has some elements in its tree: " << endl;
    bst1.insert(21);
    bst1.insert(105);
    bst1.insert(18);
    bst1.insert(16);
    bst1.insert(7);
    bst1.insert(19);
    bst1.insert(109);
    bst1.insert(125);
    bst1.insert(101);
    bst2.insert(691);
    bst1 = move(bst2);
    bst1.preorderTraversal();
    cout << endl;
}
```

**BST.h**

```
#ifndef BST_H
#define BST_H

#include <string>       
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>

using namespace std;

class Node
{
    friend class BST;
public:
    Node() : data(0), rlink(nullptr), llink(nullptr) {}
    ~Node() {}
private:
    int data;
    Node *rlink, *llink;
};

class BST
{
public:
    BST();

    BST(const BST& otherBST); 

    BST(BST&& otherBST); 

    void insert(int item);

    void insertNonRecursive(int item);

    void preorderTraversal() const;

    // BST& operator=(const BST& otherBST); 

    BST& operator=(BST&& otherBST); 

    void destroyTree();

    ~BST();

private:
    Node * root; // Pointer to the root.

    void copyConstructor(const Node *p);

    void insert(Node* &p, Node *newNode);

    void preorderTraversal(const Node *p) const;

    void destroyTree(Node *&p);
};

#endif
```

**BST.cpp**

```
#include "BST.h"

BST::BST() : root(nullptr) {}

BST::BST(const BST& otherBST) {
    copyConstructor(otherBST.root);
}

BST::BST(BST&& otherBST) {
    root = move(otherBST.root);

    otherBST.root = nullptr;
}

void BST::copyConstructor(const Node *p) {
    if (p != nullptr) {
        insert(p->data);
        copyConstructor(p->llink);
        copyConstructor(p->rlink);
    }
}


void BST::insert(int insertItem)
{
    Node  *newNode = new Node;
    newNode->data = insertItem;
    insert(root, newNode);
}

void BST::insert(Node* &p, Node *newNode)
{
    if (p == nullptr)
        p = newNode;
    else if (p->data > newNode->data)
        insert(p->llink, newNode);
    else
        insert(p->rlink, newNode);
}

void BST::insertNonRecursive(int item) {
    if (root == nullptr) {
        root = new Node();
        root->data = item;
    }
    else {
        Node *current = root;
        bool searching = true;

        while (searching) {
            if (item > current->data && current->rlink != nullptr) {
                current = current->rlink;
            }
            else if (item < current->data && current->llink != nullptr) {
                current = current->llink;
            }
            else if (item == current->data) {
                cerr << "The item to insert is already in the list, duplicates are not allowed." << endl;
                searching = false;
            }
            else {
                if (item > current->data) {
                    current->rlink = new Node();
                    current->rlink->data = item;
                }
                else {
                    current->llink = new Node();
                    current->llink->data = item;
                }

                searching = false;
            }
        }
    }
}

void BST::preorderTraversal() const {
    if (root == nullptr)
        cerr << "There is no tree.";
    else
    {
        preorderTraversal(root);
    }
}

void BST::preorderTraversal(const Node *p) const {
    if (p != nullptr) {
        cout << p->data << " ";
        preorderTraversal(p->llink);
        preorderTraversal(p->rlink);
    }
}

BST& BST::operator=(BST&& otherBST) {
    if (this != &otherBST) {
        if (root) {
            stack <Node*> nodeStack;
            nodeStack.push(root);

            Node *currentNode = nullptr;
            while (!nodeStack.empty()) {
                currentNode = nodeStack.top();
                nodeStack.pop();

                if (currentNode->rlink) {
                    nodeStack.push(currentNode->rlink);
                }
                if (currentNode->llink) {
                    nodeStack.push(currentNode->llink);
                }

                delete currentNode;
                currentNode = nullptr;
            }
            cout << root << endl; // This is where it seems like root is not being deleted correctly/nullptr'd.
        }

        root = move(otherBST.root);
        otherBST.root = nullptr;
    }
    else {
        cerr << "ERROR: Cannot assign to self." << endl;
    }

    return *this;
}

void BST::destroyTree(Node* &p)
{
    if (p != nullptr)
    {
        destroyTree(p->llink);
        destroyTree(p->rlink);
        delete p;
        p = nullptr;
    }
}

void  BST::destroyTree()
{
    destroyTree(root);
}

BST::~BST()
{
    destroyTree(root);
}
```

Comment: You never set `root` to null, or change its value.  It will have whatever value it had prior to deleting (and is a _dangling pointer_, since the memory it refers to has been deleted).

Comment: You store root pointer **value** in nodeStack, so root variable still has its value even if actual memory deleted already. You should nullify it manually. And there is no need to nullify **currentNode** 'cos it's just a temporal variable, you don't change original variable anyhow (and you can't actually)

Comment: If I just nullify it will it leave any dangling pointers??? I don’t want root variable to still have its value. Can you guide me to how I can fix this properly? Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

I think the line you mentioned is just fine and is not leaking anything. It is just that the pointer isn't assigned to NULL.
You are probably doing expecting pA tobe NULL in below example

```
int *pA = new int;
int *pB = pA;
delete pB;
pB=NULL;

printf("pA=0x%p, pB=0x%p", pA,pAB);
```

Note that even though pA points to something,which is a dangling pointer now, there is no leak.

To get desired behavior, you can set the root to NULL after you are done pushing in stack.

Comment: How can I get rid of the dangling pointers? I want it to be nullified as well as no dangling pointers. Do you know how?

Comment: You can use smart pointers. That way you dont access the pointer directly, but a wrapper to it provides you services that you need. But, with pointers, you have to manually do a lot of mandatory things. That's where newbies make mistake and give up. It requires a bit of patience and some practice.

Comment: I can’t use smart pointers for this. Is there a way I can clear this out without dangling pointers and nullify it? I’ve tried to reposition some of the statements but it doesn’t seem to work out and I’ve never really done stack work before so I’m not sure how I can do this. Could you offer further guidance?

Comment: I already mentioned for this case : "To get desired behavior, you can set the root to NULL after you are done pushing in stack."